# change current working directory in python

Tags: python

I made a folder on my desktop with the name "headfirstpython" and I need to change my current working directory to that folder and to the sub folder inside of it. I used os.getcwd() to get the current folder and it gives me 'C\Python32'. I used os.chdir('../headfirstpython/chapter3') to change the directory but its telling it cannot find the path

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Python32'
>>> os.chdir('../headfirstpython/chapter 3')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
os.chdir('../headfirstpython/chapter 3')
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified:         '../headfirstpython/chapter 3'
>>> os.chdir('../headfirstpython/chapter3')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
os.chdir('../headfirstpython/chapter3')
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified:   '../headfirstpython/chapter3'
>>>
```

Comment: Maybe it is wrong kind of slash (`/ instead of \\ `) that causing it?

Comment: Folders on the "Desktop" are not in the root directory, so that relative path will not work. Try e.g. `"\\Users\\<your user name>\\Desktop\\the path"` (or similar, don't remember the exact path).

Comment: can you try as @JoachimPileborg said, i think that will work.

Comment: In your own words, if the current working directory is `C:\\Python32` and you want to find a folder named `chapter 3` that is in a folder named `headfirstpython`, that is on your desktop, **why do you think** that `'../headfirstpython/chapter 3'` is the relative path to that folder? **What do you think** is the path of the desktop? (Hint: it is **not** `C:\\`.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think a few things may be helpful.

It looks like you're on a windows system, so you should use double back slashes '\\' to separate the folders.

Second, if you're trying to change to a folder within the current folder, you should use a single dot, and not two, e.g. os.chdir('.\\folder')

Finally, if the folder you are trying to access is not a direct subfolder of the current working directory (or otherwise in your path), you need to include the full path to access it. Since you said it's on your desktop, you'd probably want something that looks like this:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\headfirstpython') ## Where username is replaced with your actual username
```

From here, you could also change directories to the chapter3 subdirectory with the following

```
os.chdir('chapter3')
```

Which is equivalent in this case with

```
os.chdir('.\\chapter3')
```

or, if you want to be wordy:

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\headfirstpython\\chapter3')
```

Hopefully that helps?

Comment: In the book it just tells me to create a folder but not where so I just made a folder on the desktop. But this does clear things up.

Comment: "It looks like you're on a windows system, so you should use double back slashes '\\' to separate the folders." **This is bad advice** - please see [How should I write a Windows path in a Python string literal?](/q/2953834).