# Changing directory with python script doesnt work

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

i am trying to change the current directory but it is not working because it requires root privileges.Can anyone tell me how can i get the root privileges to change the directory( linux ).

```
import os
os.chdir('~/.jenkins/jobs/pip2/builds/32')
```

Comment: What was the error code?

Comment: No such file or directory: '~/.jenkins/jobs/pip2/builds/32'....... but it is there

Comment: Possible duplicate of: (Check this question) [change current working directory in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796355/change-current-working-directory-in-python)

Comment: \\ not working and / is working with a directory that doesnt require root privileges

Comment: Run the script as root user.

Comment: Hmm, try typing the full path instead of ~/.

Comment: not working @wobbily_col