# Error message when I use function for file

Tags: python, txt

What is going wrong here? I try to read my txt file in a function.. :

```
def vragen_ophalen():
    text_file = open("vragen.txt", "r")
    print(text_file.read())



def main():
    vragen_ophalen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/buni/Desktop/Leiden/iipr/Huiswerk python/sorteerhoed_concept.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()  
  File "/Users/buni/Desktop/Leiden/iipr/Huiswerk python/sorteerhoed_concept.py", line 8, in main
    vragen_ophalen()
  File "/Users/buni/Desktop/Leiden/iipr/Huiswerk python/sorteerhoed_concept.py", line 2, in vragen_ophalen
    text_file = open("vragen.txt", "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'vragen.txt'
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I added the error

Comment: well, do you have a file named `vragen.txt` under `/Users/buni/Desktop/Leiden/iipr/Huiswerk python/`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python open() gives IOError: Errno 2 No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201928/python-open-gives-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: You need to give the full directory of your text file like `/Users/buni/Desktop/Leiden/iipr/Huiswerk python/vragent.txt`

Comment: Your `python` file and `vragen.txt` doesn't exist in same folder

Comment: Oh wauw... I added the txt file in iipr, but in the wrong map :/

Comment: no worries, but please read the error messages carefully as often times they tell you what/why issue is raised