# I have received a file not found error, and name error although the file is in the same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a short program that reads lines in columns A, B, C and D in Excel, but keep receiving a file not found error and name error.

```
import csv
with open(London_Underground_data) as fp
    rows = list(csv.reader(fp))
for row in rows:
    for column in row[1:]:
        print(rows)
```

Comment: `London_Underground_data` is a variable name of a variable that doesn't exist. `open` expects a string as argument. You write a string by using quotes `''`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python open() gives FileNotFoundError/IOError: Errno 2 No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201928/python-open-gives-filenotfounderror-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `London_Underground_data` is the name of your file in the directory:

```
import csv
with open("London_Underground_data") as fp
    rows = list(csv.reader(fp))
for row in rows:
    for column in row[1:]:
        print(rows)
```

Wrap your file name in quotes. `open` expects a string, and `London_Underground_data` is a variable name.

Alternate solution:

```
London_Underground_data = "/path/to/file"
import csv
with open(London_Underground_data) as fp
    rows = list(csv.reader(fp))
for row in rows:
    for column in row[1:]:
        print(rows)
```

Comment: I have tried that, but have now encountered a unicode error.