# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CiviCRM_Indata/utdata/2021-10-12/nyaMedlemmar.csv'

Tags: python, csv

Why does this Python code give rise to Error 2 [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ?

```
import csv
from datetime import date
today=date.today()
datum=today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
nyMedlemFile = open('CiviCRM_Indata/utdata/'+datum+'/nyaMedlemmar.csv', 'w')
nyMedlem = csv.writer(nyMedlemFile)
```

I am writing so the file should not be expected to exist. I am puzzled!

Claes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python open() gives FileNotFoundError/IOError: Errno 2 No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201928/python-open-gives-filenotfounderror-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.