# The command i want to execute cannot find the file

Tags: python, module, file-not-found

I try to execute command in cmd from Python and save the output. I have the following code:

```
import subprocess
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
MyOut = subprocess.Popen("pytr portfolio",
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
stdout,stderr = MyOut.communicate()

chart_data = []
days = []
t = 0
new_char = stdout.split()
print(new_char)
netValue = float(new_char[new_char.index(b'netValue') + 2])

file = open('netValue.txt','a')
file.write(str(netValue)) 
file.write('\n')
file.close()

file = open('netValue.txt','r')
for line in file:
    t += 1
    print(line)
    chart_data.append(line)
    days.append(t)
file.close()
 
pyplot.plot(days,chart_data)
pyplot.title('depot_performance')
pyplot.show()
```

On my pc it works well but when I run this on my laptop i get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\dinok\OneDrive\Desktop\Python_Scripts\depot_statistics.py", line 9, in <module>
    MyOut = subprocess.Popen("pytr portfolio",
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

I thought it is path related so that the module is not found but was not able to find a solution. What could cause this problem and how to fixt it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [open() gives FileNotFoundError/IOError: Errno 2 No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201928/open-gives-filenotfounderror-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: No, I have not really understand it yet. I think i need more time to go through it.

Comment: I managed to fix it but i don't really know what was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) first parameter should be a list, the executable and the executable arguments. To fix it just do like the following snippet:

```py
MyOut = subprocess.Popen(["pytr", "portfolio"],
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: I still get the same error message.

Comment: Most probably the `pytr` executable is not in the `PATH`. Did you activate the Python Virtual Environment? Did you install it with `pip`?

Comment: yes i installed pytr with pip and I recieved a warning message that the directionary where pytr is installed was not in PATH. I coppied the directionary path and added it to PATH.  But nothing changed.

Comment: Try to restart the console/terminal window so the new environment variables take place. Also, make sure the path you've copied has `pytr` inside it.

Comment: There are two dictionaries wich both contained pytr. I moved pytr from the one to the other folder and then it worked.