# Saving / Editing Scrapped URLs to Directory

Tags: python, web-scraping, directory, format, clean-urls

I have successfully scrapped links from a website and I want to save them to a local folder already created called "HerHoops" for parsing later. In the past, I have successfully done this, but this website's links need a little more cleaning up.

So far this is my code. I want to keep everything after "box_score" in the link so that the saved filename includes the date and teams playing. Also saved in write mode ("w+").

```
url = f"https://herhoopstats.com/stats/wnba/schedule_date/2004/6/1/"
data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
matchup_table = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "schedule"})[0]

links = matchup_table.find_all('a')
links = [l.get("href") for l in links]
links = [l for l in links if '/box_score/' in l]

box_scores_urls = [f"https://herhoopstats.com{l}" for l in links]

for box_scores_url in box_scores_urls:
      data = requests.get(box_scores_url)
      # within loop opening up page and saving to folder in write mode
      with open("HerHoops/{}".format(box_scores_url[46:]), "w+") as f:
         # write to the files
         f.write(data.text) 
      time.sleep(3)
```

The error is

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'HerHoops/2004/06/01/new-york-liberty-vs-charlotte-sting/'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [open() gives FileNotFoundError / IOError: '\[Errno 2\] No such file or directory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201928/open-gives-filenotfounderror-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error itself its clear that you are trying to write to the file 'HerHoops/2004/06/01/new-york-liberty-vs-charlotte-sting/', but part of the directory does not exist
We can create the necessary directories by using the `os.makedirs()` function before writing to the file

Full code

```
import os
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from datetime import datetime

url = f"https://herhoopstats.com/stats/wnba/schedule_date/2004/6/1/"
data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
matchup_table = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "schedule"})[0]

links = matchup_table.find_all('a')
links = [l.get("href") for l in links]
links = [l for l in links if '/box_score/' in l]

box_scores_urls = [f"https://herhoopstats.com{l}" for l in links]

for box_scores_url in box_scores_urls:
    data = requests.get(box_scores_url)
    # extract date and teams from the box_scores_url
    date_str = datetime.strptime(re.sub(r'\D', '', url), "%Y%m%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    # Get the latter part of the string using slicing
    match = re.search(r'\d+(?!.*\d)', box_scores_url.replace('/', ''))
    teams_str = box_scores_url.replace('/', '')[match.end():]
    # create the directory if it doesn't exist
    directory = f"HerHoops/"
    os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)
    # within loop opening up page and saving to folder in write mode
    with open(f"{directory}{date_str}-{teams_str}.html", "w+") as f:
        # write to the file
        f.write(data.text)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Thank you for this as it has gotten me closer to the desired outcome. However, this has now created new folders within this new folder titled that then require a further step to reach a file called index in another newly created folder. Also, I would like to keep the directory name "HerHoops" as this specific date is a test before creating a larger loop through the whole season.

Comment: so you want to make path to file as "HerHoops/2004-06-01/houston-comets-vs-phoenix-mercury/index.html" ?

Comment: Looking to make a path to the folder "HerHoops" with filenames that include the exact date and the teams involved i.e. (2004-06-01/houston-comets-vs-phoenix-mercury.html). Apologies as I have been unclear. Appreciate the patience and help.

Comment: try the updated code path should be now as "HerHoops/2004-06-01/houston-comets-vs-phoenix-mercury.html"

Comment: It seems like it still created a nested folder within HerHoops. In my explorer, it shows up as >HerHoops\2004-06-01 then the html on the dropdown. Instead of just a folder >HerHoops with htmls.

Comment: try now path should be "HerHoops/2004-06-01-houston-comets-vs-phoenix-mercury.html"
only single folder

Comment: Ok this latest edit works and just saves under the folder HerHoops which is the goal! Thank you very much.